# iOS State Restoration of UITabBarController Does Not Restore Child View Controllers or Selected Index

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, state, tabbarcontroller

(This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow, so forgive me if there are issues)

My problem comes down to not being able to properly restore the state of a `UITabBarController`. This is a tab-based application and I am not using Storyboards.

I have opted into state restoration. I have provided all of my custom `ViewController`s with unique restoration identifiers and restoration classes in their respective `init` methods.

As for the `UITabBarController`, I provide it with a unique restoration identifier when it is created. Because I do not give it a restoration class, I have implemented the following code in the app delegate:

```
- (UIViewController *)application:(UIApplication *)application viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents coder:(NSCoder *)coder 
{
    UITabBarController *vc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    vc.restorationIdentifier = [identifierComponents lastObject];

    if ([identifierComponents count] == 1) {
        self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    }

    return vc;
}
```

I have used the same method in other apps to restore the state of `NavigationController`s, and everything goes smoothly. However, when I do it for this app with the `TabBarController`, the application launches with an empty `TabBarController` (the `TabBarController` is restored, but it does not restore it's child view controllers).

This isn't a huge shock to me, I suppose that just by nature `UITabBarController`s do not keep references to their child view controllers not the selected tab index for state restoration. However, despite many hours searching online, I could not any instructions on how to preserve the state of a `TabBarController` (without `storyboard`). Any help on how to do this would be tremendously appreciated.

Again, I'm sorry if I did not provide enough detail or wasn't clear enough. Please just let me know what you need in your answers and I'll provide it. I know I didn't provide much of my code, but I really just need instructions on how to preserve the state of a Tab-based application without storyboards. It does not need to be tailored to my specific case; I will be able to apply the general process myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode each child's view controller.
But iOS docs state that you don't decode these - that bit will happen automagically.

```
override func encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(child0VC, forKey:"child0VC")
    coder.encodeObject(child1VC, forKey:"child1VC")
    super.encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}
```

Comment: you can decode them if you need to insert them back into the hierarchy later

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue too, and since it was my first time implementing the state restoration paradigm, wondered if maybe I was doing something wrong.

In my situation, I'm programmatically creating the view controller hierarchy in `application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (which is before state restoration is executed), based on persistent state (login status, etc.). I have a root tab bar controller for which I wanted to store the selected index (at the least) and I expected the default `encodeRestorableState` and `decodeRestorableState` methods to take care of this. They didn't.

So I ended up subclassing UITabBarController just for this purpose. It's in Swift, but I assume you can read it. Add breakpoints to be sure these methods are being called.

```
class LPTabBarController: UITabBarController
{
    let selectedIndexKey = "selectedIndexKey"

    override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(selectedIndex, forKey: selectedIndexKey)
        super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
    }

    override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
        selectedIndex =  coder.decodeInteger(forKey: selectedIndexKey)
    }
}
```

As a side note, it is my opinion that NSUserDefaults should not be used for such ephemeral UI state as a selected tab bar index.

Comment: That’s odd because it does encode the selected tab, it just doesn’t encode the child controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults to set the state and you should alloc the tabBar globally rather than in method if you are using it most of time. If you do initialise the tabBar everytime then it will not state the previous state. Because creating a new reference to the object will discard previous changes and you might not be able to save state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The NSUserDefaults makes perfect sense to me as a solution (although it seems silly that the tabBarController does not keep a reference to it automatically for state restoration), but I am having trouble understanding the global alloc part of your solution. When I use a navigationController, for instance, I alloc it based on when I need it in my code. When state preservation is implemented, the  view controller at the top of the navigation stack is restored. Are you saying this is not the case for tabBarController? It does not preserve the state of it's children?

Comment: @EricElmoznino I mean to say if you are using that tabBarController everywhere then you should go for global declaration. And check that there is no multiple initialisation for the tabBar.

Answer (score 0):

UISplitViewController has the same issue. You can work around it by encoding/decoding the childViewControllers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My observation is that `UITabBarController` stores the selection in terms of restoration identifiers (at least on iOS 14).

If all you want to achieve is restoring the previously selected tab, then:

- Assign restoration identifiers to the tab bar controller and its children
- Create your view controller hierarchy in `-application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`didFinish` would be too late as it is being run after the restoration process)

With the above, state restoration should be able to look up the previously selected child (which was initialized by your regular startup logic) using restoration identifier and the tab bar controller would restore the selection on its own.